# How to add button inside input field

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input-field

Trying to copy some front end mentor challenges I am right now styling input field. I want to do 3 things right now.

1. I want to display the button inside the input field (even though I made it inside it is not perfect fit)
2. display the error icon inside the input field.
3. display the message "please provide a valid Email" below the textbox.

Right now it displays like this

[image]

```css
.left button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -104px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 48px;
}

.left input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  width: 60%;
}

.left .error {}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
  <img src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="" class="error">
  <button type="submit"><img src="/images/icon-arrow.svg " ></button>
  <small>please provide a valid Email</small>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the svg as a data-uri or upload it to imgur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have different border radius - the button and the input. How could they be perfect match? Also different height.
As for the "hint" line, just place it under in it's own `div`.
I've tweaked a little your example using `float:left` and some adjustments. It's not perfect implementation but looks ok. Note `height + padding = 48px`.

```css
.my-input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.left input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  padding-right: 113px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 22px;
  float: left;

}

.left button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -101px;
  top: 1px;
}

.left .error {}

my-input-group
```

```html
<form action="#" class="left">
  <div class="my-input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">

    <button type="submit"><img src="/images/icon-arrow.svg "></button>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="error">
      <small>please provide a valid Email</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<img src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="" class="error">
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.it worked. just a correction that i increased the height of inpult field from 22px to 50px.so it matches the height of button

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple use of css **display: flex** will solve your problem, also I have made a **container** to store your input, button & image and gave that container a border so now it visually looks like they are **inside the input box**.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
}

button img {
  height: 100%;
  filter: invert();
}

small {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
    <button type="submit">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2989/2989988.png" >
    </button>
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/7068/7068033.png" alt="image" class="error">
  </div>
  <small>please provide a valid Email</small>
</form>
```